# Create a Week Number from a Date Inclusive Starting at 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking at creating a week number from a static point, which is the Date of birth (2009). The week of birth (centered around the cut-off of 6 April 2009 - inclusive) is considered week 1.  Weeks after the first increment the value by 1.  Weeks prior count backward starting at -1.  So for example:

```
Monday 23rd March-Sunday 29th March -2 
Monday 30th March-Sunday 5th April -1 
Monday 6th April-Sunday 12th April 0 
Monday 13th April-Sunday 17th April 1
```

How would I be able to write this?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is DATEDIFF.  This will give you the number of days between the birth date and the date you are checking for.  The problem is it returns 0 when the check date is equal to the birth date.  Otherwise, some simple division would get you the week number.

So to make this work, you will have to adjust the dates and the result of the division a bit to achieve the desired results.  I have attached a working code sample below.  I would suggest placing it into a scalar function in you databse.

```
-- Set the dates
DECLARE @birthDate date = '4/6/2009';
DECLARE @checkDate date = '4/4/2009'

-- the following bits should get repackaged into a function
DECLARE @birthDayAdjust int = 0;
DECLARE @weekAdjust int = -1;

IF (@checkDate >= @birthDate)
BEGIN
    -- since we are including the birthdate in the range of week 0, we need
    -- to slide it back one day if the check date is greater than or equal to it.
    SET @birthDayAdjust = -1;
    
    SET @weekAdjust = 0;
END

SET @birthDate = DATEADD(dd, @birthDayAdjust, @birthDate);

-- Return this value
PRINT (DATEDIFF(dd, @birthDate, @checkDate))/7 + @weekAdjust;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this now!